# Error: Session is already connected

Tags: ros, naoqi, pepper

I am trying to connect the pepper robot with ROS. and I have installed all the required [drivers](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/naoqi_driver) for it. When I enter the command from the terminal to connect the pepper robot, it's showing as the session is already connected as shown in the below figure.

> roslaunch pepper_bringup pepper_full.launch nao_ip:=10.55.*.* network_interface:=wlxa842a191200*

[image]

and I am using ROS-kinetic.

Comment: Hello sai, welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange. Can you please post the error trace as formatted text instead of a picture? It makes it easy for us to run text searches on the trace.